# Python OpenCV resize is slow

Tags: python, resize, opencv

When I run the resize function of OpenCV python version, it is too slow !
the following code takes ~0.21s to run. The image size is (300, 300).

```
im2 = cv2.resize(im, (128, 128)).
```

It's so weird! Any body can tell me what's wrong with this ?

OpenCV version: 3.1.0 or 3.2.0
CPU : i7 5930k

Comment: try using some other interpolation method mentioned here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize

Comment: @JeruLuke I has tried other interpolation methods. They all cost ~0.20+s. This really bothers me. Thx~

Comment: I tried using the same code snippet for a sample image on my system, it took 0.0100002288818 seconds. CPU : Core-i3

Comment: @JeruLuke Thank you for your test. I still struggle with this problem.

Comment: what is your image data type? double, int?